# Blocking or non-blocking mode linux?

Tags: linux, c

В функцию прилетает файловый дескриптор. Как узнать в блокирующем и не блокирующем режиме он находится? Вроде того:

```
int f(int fd, ...) 
{
    if(is_non_blocked(fd)) 
    {
        do_something(fd); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        kill_cat();
        exit(CAT_IS_DEAD);
    }
}
```

Ни один кот не пострадал!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя функцию

```
int flag;
flag = fcntl(fd,F_GETFL);
if( flag != -1){
  if( (flag & O_NONBLOCK) ){
     /*в блокирующм режиме*/
  }
}
```

Можно получить флаги связанные с файловым дескриптором.

Comment: Да, я слишком рано задал этот вопрос и буквально сразу его решил. Однако большое спасибо за ответ. Он оказался строчку короче.

Comment: А ошибки кто проверять будет?!

Comment: @0andriy согласен

Comment: if(-1 == (flag = fcntl(fd,F_GETFL))) sys_error(errno, UNIX_FCNTL, "fcntl()"); // Проверил :)